# Why some lines are highlighted with a green rectangle and how to turn it off in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Working on a code kata I faced behavior which can be seen on a screenshot.

A piece of code outside the page length is fixed and does not respond to the position of the cursor. I have not seen this before in other projects I was working on. What is that and how I can turn it off?

[image]

Also, when mouse pressed on this green rectangle, my keyboard language is switched.

**Update:**  When I go to the declaration or usages of the method, this rectangle seems to be out of editor bounds.

[image]

Comment: Try disabling all 3rd custom plugins including the UI Themes plugins if you have installed any.

Comment: Good idea, I have updated the One Dark theme plugin, and it looks like it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling all 3rd custom plugins including the UI Themes plugins if you have installed any.